# Select stats from different days

Tags: php, mysql

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Right now I am doing it this way..

```
$m= date("m");
$de= date("d");
$y= date("Y");
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//today
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$today = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM cdr 
                      WHERE accountcode = '$userid' 
                        AND calldate LIKE '$date%'") or die(mysql_error());
$counttoday = mysql_num_rows($today);
//yesterday
$yesterdaydate = date('m/d/Y', mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-1),$y));
$yesterday = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                          FROM cdr 
                          WHERE accountcode = '$userid' 
                            AND calldate LIKE '$yesterdaydate%'") or die(mysql_error());
$countyesterday = mysql_num_rows($yesterday);
```

then

```
print $counttoday;
print $countyesterday;
```

I know there has to be a better way to do this.

Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Do you only need the value of mysql_num_rows() or do you _fetch_ all those records anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an absolute better way to do what you're trying to do, but you can use the MySQL statement COUNT() to count the number of rows returned by a query.

So for example, writing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM cdr 
WHERE accountcode = '$userid' 
AND calldate LIKE '$date%'
```

Will return a 1x1 table of results with the number of rows in the query.
Then you can use

```
$counttoday = mysql_result($today, 0);
```

to fetch the count.

There doesn't seem to be a faster way to do this with one function call, unless you define your own function I suppose. But for a very large result from your initial query, I would imagine this is faster since I assume mysql_num_rows() has to count each row individually all over again. Doing it this way only goes over the rows of the query result once, when the result itself is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt this work?

```
SELECT calldate, COUNT(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE accountcode = '$userid' AND (calldate LIKE '$today%' OR calldate LIKE '$yesterday%')
```

Answer (score 0):

why is today Y-m-d while yesterday is m/d/Y ?

```
$yesterdaydate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
```

calldate in the table should be date or datetime. Then you can simply use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') `calldate`, COUNT(calldate) `count` FROM cdr WHERE accountcode = '$userid' AND calldate >= '$yesterdaydate' group by calldate
```

You can compare calldate to $yesterdaydate to find out if it is yesterdays or todays count.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers didn't mention it, it can actually be done in a single query, like so:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));

$mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DATE(`calldate`) = '$today') `today`, 
    COUNT(DATE(`calldate`) = '$yesterday') `yesterday`
    FROM `cdr`
    WHERE `accountcode` = '$userid' 
        AND DATE(`calldate`) IN ('$today', '$yesterday')");
```

This returns the count for today in the first column and the count for yesterday in the second column.

If `calldate` is already a `DATE` field, you can leave off the `DATE()` cast; that would improve the performance in fact.